# 12.04 - Steam is running in the system monitor, but will not open

Tags: 12.04, steam

I am on Ubuntu 12.04, and have installed Steam and had it running previously but for the past 2-3 days, whenever I try to run Steam it opens a dialog box that says Verifying installation and then it closes and nothing happens. When I try to run Steam through terminal it gives me this:

> Running Steam on ubuntu 12.04 32-bit
>   STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
>   Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
>   Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
>   Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
>   unlinked 0 orphaned pipes
>   removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3130 with name 0eBlobRegistryMutex_F8AC220EF1CF9E5DA3A138E83771D64C
>   removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3130 with name 0eBlobRegistrySignal_F8AC220EF1CF9E5DA3A138E83771D64C
>   removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3130 with name 0emSteamEngineInstance
>   removing stale semaphore last operated on by process 3130 with name 0eSteamEngineLock
>   Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1378500910_client)
>   [0914/114403:WARNING:proxy_service.cc(958)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation

Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have found that if you remove the appcache with "rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam/appcache", it fixes the issue, must have been a Steam update that broke it.

Answer (score 2):

Just run `rm -Rf ~/.steam/steam/appcache`

Comment: While this may be the correct answer, in future, when you post an answer, could you explain how running code samples will help. This may help other in the future determine whether this is the route they should take.